# Jquery code insert into WP HeadWay Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi problem is to insert jquery code into WP Headway Page.

Short intro
I'm using Wordpress Headway theme manager and it consist of 5 posts. 
I want to make jQuery Carousel with links to content (carousel works as WP plugin). 
Headway has custom code section, tried to insert there.

Can someone elaborate how to insert jQuery script into single Headway Page.

Comment: Can  you post your code so we can see what you have tried so far?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    document.write('Worked!');
    });

</script>

Comment: JS code appears to be generated in middle between body tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too thought this was a HeadWay issue, but it is [a WordPress issue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript).

My solution was to add a JS in my "Child" theme folder and link to it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/childTheme/js/indexTabs.js"></script>
```

If you need to use another library like jQuery, just add it above the JS call

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I added both these lines to the bottom of the post (jQuery call before the JS)